# trying to find simpler way to reference type of subclass from trait

Tags: scala, inheritance, types, covariance

so, here's a bit of a contrived example:

```
trait MyTrait { 
  type T <: MyTrait
  val listOfT:List[T]
  def getFirst:T
  //def getOne:T = if( listOfT.length > 0 ) { getFirst } else { this }
}

class MyClass extends MyTrait {
  type T = MyClass
  override val listOfT:List[T] = List[MyClass](this)
  override def getFirst:T = listOfT.head
}
```

The question sort of has two parts:

Is there some other way to do this where the return types in MyClass could just be "MyClass" instead of having to specify "type T = MyClass" ?  Basically I want to be able to add this trait to a class without really having to have the subclass change its implementation significantly or think about the type system...  to just return members of itself, and have the trait accept anything as long as it is covariant on the subtype.  Does this even make sense?

in MyTrait, if uncommented, getOne method will give an error "type mismatch:"
 found   : MyTrait.this.type (with underlying type MyTrait)
 required: MyTrait.this.T

If I were to change the return type to this.type, I'd get the opposite found/required type mismatch.  Either return value actually has the same type (and is actually the same object).

What's the correct way to handle these kinds of situations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
trait MyTrait[T <: MyTrait[T]] { self: T =>
  val listOfT: List[T]
  def getFirst: T
  def getOne: T = if (listOfT.length > 0) getFirst else self
}

class MyClass extends MyTrait[MyClass] {
  override val listOfT: List[MyClass] = List[MyClass](this)
  override def getFirst: MyClass = listOfT.head
}
```

It gets rid of `type T = MyClass` (allowing you to just put `MyClass` in a return type) and fixes the compile error in the definition of `getOne`.

Comment: hmm....  yes that works and does solve the problem.  Is there a way to do it with just extends MyTrait and not specifying extends MyTrait[MyClass]?  It seems a little weird repeating the name of the subclass in the definition, but this is definitely cleaner/simpler than how I was going about it.

Comment: `MyClass extends MyTrait[MyClass]` is actually a fairly common pattern in these kinds of cases where a trait's methods needs to know about the implementing class.  See, for example, `Seq[+A] extends SeqLike[A, Seq[A]]` in the Scala standard library.

Comment: hmm.... I just noticed though, now if in MyClass I want to call getOne, I can't assign the result to a variable of type MyClass because it's a MyTrait[MyClass]?

Comment: hmm.... now if I want to add a companion object to trait MyTrait (object MyTrait), how do I refer to the type of MyTrait from the companion object?  It needs a type parameter but I don't have one in this context :-/